# Is it possible to create CloudWatch Logs destination for Kinesis Data Stream via console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm searching to know if is it possible to create a logs destination for Kinesis data for cross-account via Amazon console.

I've found this demo from AWS user guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CreateDestination.html, I would like to do the same via WEB interface of AWS

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you writing log messages to a Kinesis stream and want to send them on to CloudWatch Logs? If yes, the short answer is that you'll need a Lambda. If no, please describe your actual use-case in more detail.

Comment: @Parsifal I'm implementing the Centralized Logging solution. I'm trying to make a Kinesis Data Streams subscription of a centralized account to a test account who produce logs. For this, I need to create a destination in the Centralized Logs account. The demo proposes only CLI calls to do it. I want to know if I can create the destination with WEB interface

Comment: you can perform individual steps from document on AWS console. But for `put-destination` and `put-destination-policy` you need to use AWS CLI or cloudformation.